# SQL Server Service Broker :message stays at sender queue for some time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, service-broker

I am using SQL Server 2014 Service Broker, and I created a service that sends messages from sender to target, and my message arrive target and everything is ok.

But what I don't understand is why at sender queue when a message is added to a sender queue, it is not sent directly to target queue, it waits for some time which I don't know if it is configurable

Is there any way to tell service broker to send message instantly once it arrives sender queue and don't wait for some time?

My configuration at sender is :

```
CREATE ROUTE HadoopRouteDataSender
AUTHORIZATION dbo
WITH
    SERVICE_NAME = '//Audit/DataWriter',
    BROKER_INSTANCE = '830B71C9-C0F4-4DE2-A823-5E28BC14ADC8',   
    ADDRESS = 'TCP://192.168.88.20:4022'
GO

CREATE MESSAGE TYPE [//Photo/Message] 
    VALIDATION = NONE

CREATE CONTRACT [//photo/Contract]
    ([//Photo/Message]  SENT BY INITIATOR)

CREATE QUEUE dbo.HadoopInitiatorAuditQueue

CREATE SERVICE [tcp://192.168.1.105:4022/HadoopSender/Audit/DataSender] 
    AUTHORIZATION dbo
    ON QUEUE dbo.HadoopInitiatorAuditQueue -- no contract means service can only be the initiator
```

Comment: Service Broker is inherently asynchronous. We use SB in our environment and for remote destinations (i.e. where the target queue is on another server), I see a cadence where messages will get sent in a batch every ≈ 30 seconds. But they get there eventually.

Comment: is 30 seconds is a default time or i can configure that to be 3 seconds for example ,what is this configuration called ?

Comment: I've found no way to configure that

Comment: i am too, i think because service broker is asynchronous, there is no possibility to manage this time but i have not found any references that describe when service broker decides to send a bunch of data and if that is configurable